# Difference between the vacated position and the vacant position

Tags: difference

Is there some difference between `the vacated position` and `the vacant position`?

I googled both words and seems `vacant` is used more. But I couldn't find the information if there is a difference between them.

Comment: The difference can be found [here](http://the-difference-between.com/vacant/vacate)

Comment: I recommend, for the sake of simplicity, using *vacant* when both terms apply.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**'Vacate'** means to leave a previously occupied place, for example, a seat or a house. 
**'Vacant'** means a place that isn't occupied at present. The status of the chair or the house (or where ever it may be) after a person vacates from it is *'vacant'*. 
So a *'vacant'* position means that the position is unoccupied now. It may have been vacated or it could've never been occupied in the first place. A *'vacated'* position means that there was somebody who was occupying that position and now, that place is unoccupied. That is the significant difference between the words. 
This is the Merriam-Webster definition of [vacant](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/vacant.) and [vacate](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/vacate).